# Compare data and return results on different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare the table records in SQL Server. I have the data in this format:

| ParentItem | ChildItem | Version | Color | PG# |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | 0 | clear | 33 |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | 1 | clear | 3 |

So in the above table I want to get the different between two version (0,1) data for column (Color and PG #).

So the desired output would look like:

| ParentItem | ChildItem | Version | ColumnName | OldValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | 1 | Color | NULL | NULL |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | 1 | PG# | 33 | 3 |

If there is no change then we will show the null otherwise the difference.

So I want the SQL script to get the data.

Comment: Why are they  both version 1 in your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

An approach based on unpivoting the table and conditional aggregation is a possible option:

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES  
   ('VP10334', 'VP10334', 0, 'clear', '33'),
   ('VP10334', 'VP10334', 1, 'clear', '3')
) v (ParentItem, ChildItem, Version, Color, PG#)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   d.ParentItem, d.ChildItem, a.ColumnName,
   OldValue = NULLIF(MAX(CASE WHEN d.Version = 0 THEN Value END), MAX(CASE WHEN d.Version = 1 THEN Value END)),
   NewValue = NULLIF(MAX(CASE WHEN d.Version = 1 THEN Value END), MAX(CASE WHEN d.Version = 0 THEN Value END))
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   ('Color', Color),
   ('PG#', PG#)
) a (ColumnName, Value)  
GROUP BY d.ParentItem, d.ChildItem, a.ColumnName
```

Result:

| ParentItem | ChildItem | ColumnName | OldValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | Color | *null* | *null* |
| VP10334 | VP10334 | PG# | 33 | 3 |

Comment: thanks for your time and reply there is only 1 issue in the above statement is 
for Color its showing the same value in oldValue and NewValue column.

Comment: Also where are are comparing the column values

Comment: @user987372, `NULLIF` compares the values or returns `NULL`: _NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression._

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more flexible approach you can perhaps use this FOR JSON trick:

```sql
SELECT  parentItem, ChildItem, MAX(version) AS Version,[Key] AS ColumnName
,   CASE WHEN MIN(Value) <> MAX(Value) THEN MIN(Value) END AS oldValue
,   CASE WHEN MIN(Value) <> MAX(Value) THEN MAX(Value) END AS newValue
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'VP10334', N'VP10334', 0, N'clear', 33)
    ,   (N'VP10334', N'VP10334', 1, N'clear', 3)
) t (ParentItem,ChildItem,Version,Color,PG#)
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    OPENJSON((SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) x
        WHERE   x.[key] NOT IN ('ParentItem', 'ChildItem', 'Version')
    ) jx
GROUP BY parentItem, ChildItem, [key]
```

It has support for any number of columns to compare without specifically writing them out.

`OPENJSON((SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))` is a kind of dynamic unpivot which creates a Key, Value combination of columns and Values.

By then aggregating it per Key, we can compare the MIN/MAX values and display your output.

Note that this doesn't handle NULLs correctly